# Check if the sum is equal to the polynomial

Tags: summation

I have the following polynomial
$$(1-\alpha)+3\alpha\beta\gamma+4\alpha\beta\gamma[(1-\beta)+(1-\gamma)]+5\alpha\beta\gamma[(1-\beta)^2+(1-\beta)(1-\gamma)+(1-\gamma)^2]+\cdots$$

I believe I can write it as $$(1-\alpha)+\alpha\beta\gamma\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^n(1-\beta)^{n-i}(1-\gamma)^i(i+3).$$ Is this true?

Comment: If by the $+\dots$ in the first expression you mean what I think you mean, then yes. But it is not a polynomial in anything but $\alpha$, and we would need to deal with issues of convergence.

Comment: Shouldn't the last term be $(n+3)$ not $(i+3)$?

Comment: Well $0\leq \alpha,\beta,\gamma\leq 1$.